# PHP POST method problem, uploading recipe

Tags: php, mysql, post, methods

[the interface of uploading recipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFgrP.png)This is my code to upload recipes(new.php), once the submit button is clicked, it will be uploaded to mysql. I have tried checking if any mysql codes were outdated by changing them to mysqli. Cause this project is a bit old. So on other pages I have changed many mysql to mysqli.

```
<form method="post" action="new.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form3">


***I'm suspecting that the mistake is from here. As all the other parts of the code seem to be okay to me.***


    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

     $title = $_POST['title'];
     $date = date('Y.m.d');
     $author = $_POST['author'];
     $desc = $_POST['desc'];
     $image_name = $_FILES ['image'] ['name'];
     $image_type = $_FILES ['image']['type'];
     $image_size = $_FILES ['image']['size'];
     $image_tmp = $_FILES  ['image']['tmp_name'];

    if($title =='' or $author =='' or $desc ==''){
        echo"<script>alert('Some Field/fields is/are Empty')</script>";
        exit();
    }
    if($image_type=="image/jpeg" or $image_type=="image/png" or   $image_type=="image/gif"){

        if($image_size<=50000){
            move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,"uploads/$image_name");
        }
        else{
            echo"<script>alert('Image is Larger, Only 50kb size is   allowed')</script>";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo"<script>alert('Image Type is Invalid')</script>";
    }
    $query = "insert into    new_recipe(post_title,post_date,post_author,post_image,post_desc
    ) values('$title','$date','$author','$image_name','
    $desc')";

    if (mysqli_query($con,$query)){
        echo "<center><h1>Recipe Has Been Submitted!</h1></center>";
    }
}
 **Once all the details have been typed. When I click on submit , it doesn't give me any error/s. There were some previous recipes uploaded before I face these errors, and I can see them perfectly under the view.php page.**
?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**. Additionally, you should check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to see if the query is failing.

Comment: I appreciate your concern, but this particular website is just for self education purposes. But regardless, its good to know tht.

Comment: And what is your question? What is not working? What have you tried to spot the error?

Comment: I assume you did change the database connection code from the old `mysql_` API to the new `mysqli_` API ??

Comment: Do the new images get put onto your uploads folder?

Comment: @ELCapitan I think there is no problem with code. Try inserting only the fields first. and then add image code.

Comment: ___this particular website is just for self education purposes___ Then surely doing it right would be the prime function. Specially as doing it right will ease your later issue of saving a receipt written by `Peter O'Toole` and `Brian O'Driscol` etc etc

Comment: @RiggsFolly lol, I literally said that I appreciated he's concern and also its good to know that I will be vulnerable to sql injection, and yes I do appreciate your comment too. TQ

Comment: @RiggsFolly YES, the pictures do get uploaded to my uploads folder.

Comment: It may be for self education purposes, but there are two benefits to using prepared statements. The other is **never having to worry about quoting issues**. I find it removes a humungous headache, especially with names like `O'Malley`.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you by adding the ini_set ... to the top of my script, it did help me by showing the :

Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/recipe/new.php:118 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/recipe/new.php(118): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'insert into new...') #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/recipe/new.php on line 118

Comment: MySQL doesn't return errors the same way PHP does. You need to check explicitly for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).

Comment: Ahhhh nothing subtile then.... A dirty great big error :)

Comment: Always turn error reporting ON while developing

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeapp, thanks a bunch mate !